# Matlab - Symbolically Solving Inequalities

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

So, I'm trying to establish some new stability criteria for my simulations, and this involves a lot of convoluted inequalities. I've worked through the math a few times by hand, and it's very laborous; so, I wanted to figure out a way to automate the process (as I'm trying to find the best integration scheme from a stability perspective). Is there anyway to solve inequalities symbolically in Matlab? Here's what I'm trying to solve. In the following expression, `x` refers to the gradient of a force function with respect to `x`, and t is the time step.  In general, `x < 0` and `t > 0`:

```
-(t*x + (2*t^3*x + t^2*x^2 - 2*t*x + 4*t + 1)^(1/2) + 1)/(x*t^2 - 2) < 1
```

Based on what I've looked at online, this seems to be possible in MuPAD, but using the following code does not give me any valid results:

```
solve(-(t*x + (2*t^3*x + t^2*x^2 - 2*t*x + 4*t + 1)^(1/2) + 1)/(x*t^2 - 2) < 1, t)
```

Any idea what I can do to make this work and automate the process?

Comment: "[T]he following code does not give me any valid results" is not descriptive. What exactly happens and what did you expect? You seem to be assuming that there is a solution. If so, what is it? And how do you define `x` and `t`? Did you apply any `assumptions`? And, yes, as you'd discover with a simpler equation, Matlab's `solve` can handle inequalities just like MuPAD's version, though there may be differences.

Comment: @horchler When I use that code in Matlab (specifically MuPAD, as sources I've discovered claim that regular Matlab can not solve inequalities), it just gives me back the same code; it doesn't solve out the function.  I was expecting it to give me different solutions based upon different intervals, as found here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28-%28t*x+%2B+%282*t^3*x+%2B+t^2*x^2+-+2*t*x+%2B+4*t+%2B+1%29^%281%2F2%29+%2B+1%29%2F%28x*t^2+-+2%29%3C1%2Ct%29 .  I'm speculating that I'm not formulating the command properly somehow and would like some help in figuring that out

Comment: Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since Wolfram Alpha gives you [an answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7B-%28t%2ax%2B%282%2at%5E3%2ax%2Bt%5E2%2ax%5E2-2%2at%2ax%2B4%2at%2B1%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2B1%29%2F%28x%2at%5E2-2%29%3C1%2Ct%3E0%2Cx%3C0%2CIm%28t%29%3D%3D0%2CIm%28x%29%3D%3D0%7D%2Ct%5D) (that I presume you've checked for correctness), I assume you want to use Matlab to solve other similar problems. However, this is a very non-trivial inequality due to the roots of the polynomials. I haven't been able to get Matlab/MuPAD to do anything with it. As I stated, regular Matlab can solve inequalities and systems of equalities in many cases, e.g., in R2013b

```
syms x real;
solve(x^3-1>1,x)
```

Even Mathematica 9 has trouble (the [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) function can be used instead of it's `Solve`, but the output is not easy to use).

You can, however, solve for the real roots where `x < 0` and `t > 0` via

```
syms x t real;
assume(x<0);
assume(t>0);
f = -(t*x+sqrt(2*t^3*x+t^2*x^2-2*t*x+4*t+1)+1)/(x*t^2-2);
s = solve(f==1,t)
```

which returns:

```
s =

-(x + (x*(x - 2))^(1/2))/x
```

This simplifies to `sqrt((x-2)/x)-1`. Thus `t > sqrt((x-2)/x)-1`, one of the bounds provided by Wolfram Alpha. (The other more complicated bound is always less than zero and actually is the condition that ensures that `t` is real.)

But, do you even need to be solving this problem symbolically? Do you need explicit expressions for the various intervals in terms of all `x`? If not, this type of problem is probably better suited numeric approaches – either via root solving (e.g., `fzero`) or minimization (e.g., `fmincon`).

Comment: Thanks for the response; that's basically doing exactly what I was looking for.  Ideally, it would be much easier to use some kind of numerical approximation, but, unfortunately, I do need to solve it symbolically - as I'm looking for general stability criterion.  Basically, I'm just exploring my options for this type of problem and don't have any concrete values set yet.  So, this will definitely speed up my process dramatically.  Thanks for the assistance!